# MySQL cleanup table from duplicated entries AND relink FK in depending table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, duplicates

Here is my situation: I have 2 tables, `patient` and `study`.

Each table has its own PK using autoincrement.

In my case, the pat_id should be unique. It's not declared as unique at database level since it could be non unique is some uses (it's not a home made system). I found out how to configure the system to consider the pat_id as unique, but **I need now to cleanup the database for duplicated patients AND relink duplicated patients in study table to remaining unique patient**, before deleting the duplicated patients.

`Patient` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `patient` (
  `pk` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pat_id` VARCHAR(250) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
...
  `pat_name` VARCHAR(250) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
...
  `pat_custom1` VARCHAR(250) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL
....
  PRIMARY KEY (`pk`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Study table:

```
CREATE TABLE `study` (
  `pk` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `patient_fk` BIGINT(20) DEFAULT NULL,
...
  PRIMARY KEY (`pk`),
...
  CONSTRAINT `patient_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`patient_fk`) REFERENCES `patient` (`pk`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I found some similar questions, but not exactly the same issue, especially it was missing the link of the foreign keys to the remaining unique patient.

[Cleanup Update for Duplicate Entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24433306/cleanup-update-for-duplicate-entries)

[Update only first record from duplicate entries in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620038/update-only-first-record-from-duplicate-entries-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did.

I reused an unused field in `patient` table to mark non duplicated (N), 1st of duplicated (X), and other duplicated patients (Y). You could also add a column for this (and drop it after use).

Here are the steps I followed to cleanup my database:

```
/*1: List duplicated */
select pk,pat_id, t.`pat_id_issuer`, t.`pat_name`, t.pat_custom1
from patient t
where pat_id in (
select pat_id from (
select pat_id, count(*)
from patient 
group by 1
having count(*)>1
) xxx);    

/*2: Delete orphan patients */
delete from patient where pk not in (select patient_fk from study);

/*3: Reset flag for duplicated (or not) patients*/
update patient t set t.`pat_custom1`='N';

/*4: Mark all duplicated */
update patient t set t.`pat_custom1`='Y' 
where pat_id in (
select pat_id from (
select pat_id, count(*)
from patient 
group by 1
having count(*)>1
) xxx) ;

/*5: Unmark the 1st of the duplicated*/
update patient t 
join (select pk from (
select min(pk) as pk, pat_id from patient 
where  pat_custom1='Y'  
group by pat_id
) xxx ) x
on (x.pk=t.pk)
set t.`pat_custom1`='X' 
where  pat_custom1='Y'
  ;

/*6: Verify update is correct*/
select pk, pat_id,pat_custom1  
from `patient` 
where  pat_custom1!='N'
order by pat_id, pat_custom1;

/*7: Verify studies linked to duplicated patient */
select p.* from study s
join patient p on (p.pk=s.patient_fk)
where p.pat_custom1='Y';

/*8: Relink duplicated patients */
update study s
join patient p on (p.pk=s.patient_fk)
set patient_fk = (select pk from patient pp
where pp.pat_id=p.pat_id and pp.pat_custom1='X')
where p.pat_custom1='Y';

/*9: Delete newly orphan patients */
delete from patient where pk not in (select patient_fk from study);

/* 10: reset flag */
update patient t set t.`pat_custom1`=null;

/* 11: Commit changes */
commit;
```

There is certainly a shorter way, with a some smarter (complicated?) SQL, but I personally prefer the simple way. This also allows me to check each step is doing what I expect.